# Required question mark on questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have noticed that a lot of new users forget to actually ask a question when posting. They will post there code and leave, or say what the program is intended to do but not what they want changed or fixed.

I propose that a warning is generated if the user has asked a question without a ? mark appearing somewhere in there paragraph. Something like "Are you sure you asked a question?"

I know it seems a bit silly but it would stop a lot of these cases where nothing is actually asked.

Comment: Not sure how that is helpful as a post can include code, a description of what it is supposed to do, what it is actually doing to provide enough information without the poster having to add something silly such as "Can you see what I am doing wrong?".

Comment: +1 for addressing the problem. -1 for not coming up with a good fix. People will game this by just adding some weird question somewhere.

Comment: `a > b ? a : b;`

Comment: I spend a major share of my time on SE just capitalizing "i" and adding question marks. You are close to 2K now, soon you too will be able to edit and fix every post you read :)

Comment: Why does this have a negative score? I just came here to request exactly the same thing, and I feel it would be a major improvement.

Comment: @reinierpost perhaps because while the idea is sound the way I proposed to solve it does not work.

Comment: @marsh: Why not? I'm convinced that it will. And apart from that, it's wrong to downvote a question just because the answer is no.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Merely checking for the existence of a question mark is going to both have a high false positive rate, and a high false negative rate.  There are plenty of questions that make the question clear without phrasing it grammatically, and plenty of questions with a question mark that don't actually ask a clear question.  On top of that, if someone gets this message I just don't see most people adding a meaningful question if they didn't already have one; whether they have a good quesiton or not, I only see people adding a fairly meaningless "question" to the end like:

- So what do I do now?
- Can you help me?
- What did I do wrong?
- Why doesn't this work?
- This isn't a question?

None of these add any value to just not having them.

The main reaction to such a message would be to defeat the message, not *to fix the question*.

Comment: Your *hypothesis* about the "main reaction" might be true or false.  If it is true, nothing is gained.  If it is false, it will yield a considerable increase in the quality of the questions.  What will happen is something in-between: some will circumvent the mechanism by adding a question mark, others will comply and improve their questions.  The end result will *still* be a measurable increase in quality.  The overhead for implementing this mechanism is minimal, so I think it is an excellent feature request.  I would make it mandatory rather than suggestive: "ask a question or gtfo."

Comment: Not to mention that if such a mechanism is in place, and I see someone blatantly circumventing it, I will feel very justified in immediately voting to close their question.

Comment: @MikeNakis That's not addressing the fact that this is going to have both a very high false positive rate, and a very high false negative rate.  Many of the people who really don't have a clear question won't be getting this message at all, and many getting it will already have a clear question.  This is going to result in a huge amount of noise.  And to your point of closing questions that are edited to subvert the message, again, keep in mind that there'll be a high false positive rate here, so people will end up needing to subvert this message *when they already had a clear question*.

Comment: @MikeNakis The result of this change would be a lot of people making inappropriate edits (which actually cause quite a bit of noise) and people like you voting to close clear questions when you see people subverting a quality filter that was causing false positives.  Additionally, if the author was capable of asking a clear question *they almost certainly would have done so from the start*.  When someone asks an unclear question they either don't know how to ask it clearly, or already think that their question is clear.  In neither case will a prompt like this help them ask a clearer question.

Comment: The false positives are of no concern because they do no harm. With regards to the false negatives, I think this is a total non-issue. This is a question and answer site, so you should always keep in mind that you are asking a question. Specifically, you are posting a request for help.  I do not think it is unreasonable to promote a culture in which we explicitly show that we keep this in mind by carefully wording our questions so as to include an actual, honest, grammatically correct, question.

Comment: As for those who are incapable of asking a clear question even after they have been reminded to do so, I wonder: do we really want their questions on stackoverflow? Isn't quality an issue?

Comment: @MikeNakis False positive are *absolutely* an issue.  Telling people that they have a particular problem *that they do not in fact have* is very problematic.  It creates confusion for them, causes them to waste time trying to "fix" an issue that isn't in fact broken, it is going to cause them to start making edits that shouldn't be made, drawing attention to the question inappropriately, etc.  As to the false negatives, none of your points are relevant to that.  Not warning people when they in fact are doing something wrong has nothing to do with any of those points.

Comment: @MikeNakis I'm not saying that we want the questions that are unclear and that the author's can't fix.  I'm saying that, *this proposed change doesn't actually make them go away*.  The filter is so trivially subvertable that it fails to do is job of actually filtering out the questions that we don't want at all, in addition to not actually causing people to improve a question in response to the warning.

Comment: I think we misunderstood each other by what false positives and false negatives mean, but in any case, it does not matter.  I rest my case.

Comment: @Servy: What you say is true, but it doesn't imply requiring a question mark on questions is a bad idea. In my experience, good questions can practically always be summarized as a question in the title, and questions that don't state their question in the title are almost always bad questions. So for the good questions, the new rule wouldn't be much of a problem; whereas for the bad questions, there are so many of them, that even if the rule fixes only 20% of them, it would already be worthwhile.

Comment: @reinierpost I've seen *lots* of *great* questions that didn't actually contain a question mark in them.  I've seen tens of thousands of terrible questions that asked a grammatical question.  This wouldn't come anywhere *close* to improving 20% of bad questions.  Most probably already have a question mark in there somewhere, and if you go anywhere close to .1% of questions that hit this block to add a substantive question statement that conveyed clarity not in the original revision I'd be pretty surprised.  The remainder would just be adding  meaningless statement that only adds noise.

Comment: This answer is using arguments to problems that the OP does not try to solve. To improve you don't need to do any thing with false positives. False negatives are debatable. And if we can perhaps not assume the worst in our community, reminding people to ask an actual question is of course relevant. If they ask "So what do I do now?" it's at least a start: a great insight in the level of research from the OP. You can comment "What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?". People really trying to circumvent this reminder can still be down voted. But I believe many people would benefit from it

Comment: @Webber I'm not assuming the worst in the community.  Like I said, plenty of *good questions* don't need a question mark. I'm saying if someone *isn't asking a good question* that telling them to add a question mark to it isn't going to make that question any better.  If someone adds "So what do I do now" to their post, either they had a good question, and it's noise that made it worse, or it was a bad question, and they added noise to it and made it *even* worse.  In neither case did they improve it.  It's not "a start", it's just fluff.

Comment: That's a strong opinion. I would argue it's not always that black and white and that this is a valid case to be a/b tested. There are also many implementation details to be considered. Of course literally asking people to add a question mark is too naive, and strictly triggering it based on there not being a question mark too. But that doesn't make this a bad idea at all - assuming developers would really think about how to best implement an improvement to the quality of new questions by new members. I think we agree on not wanting a robotic experience, so lets not implement it in a naive way.

Comment: @Webber The proposal here *is* asking for a warning to be trigger when someone doesn't have a question mark, and is proposing telling them to ask a question.  So yes, it *is* asking for the naïve thing you agree isn't a good idea.  If you have some idea of how to recognize problematic questions and prompt them for improvement, then you should describe what you think would be a good idea, probably in a new post, as it sounds like whatever you're thinking of would be pretty different from what this is asking for.

Comment: I'm not saying we shouldn't attempt to determine questions with problems and prompt the users to fix them, I'm simply saying that the lack of a question mark is an extremely poor indicator of a question having problems, and that of questions without a question mark, telling them "Are you sure you asked a question?" is unlikely to result in meaningful improvements.  That's what this is proposing, it's not a generic proposal for "attempting to find problematic questions and prompting them to be fixed" which is really too broad of a proposal to respond to anyway.

Comment: I see. Basically we agree on all semantics but differ in how literally we interpret a question. I see value in finding solutions to the problem that's behind the question itself. I guess personally I don't see much value in interpreting and answering a meta question in a very literal way because it halts the discussion and forces it into another thread, but the idea stays the same. Perhaps I'm wrong though. In the meantime I'll consider creating a new thread.

Comment: @Webber The problem behind the question itself is that people ask bad and unclear questions, which sure, basically everyone wants to address in some way.  But just asking to "make questions better" or "block bad questions" or "suggest people fix bad questions" are all just *way* too broad. If we knew how to do that (better than we already do) *we would*, but it's hard.  If you have a specific actionable proposal for changing that, it needs to be its own post, not tacked onto the comments of some only tangentially related post from 8 years ago. You'll get much better discussions of it that way.

Comment: Fair enough. Just to be clear though: By challenging the status quo in the only relevant thread I could find, I don't necessarily mean to tuck anything away. The intention should always be to incrementally improve.