# What elements could be required for beginners' posts?

Tags: feature-request

Especially for users with low rep, I think there could be requirements for a question that would

- Automate the task of blocking out lazy questions
- Expedite the poster's learning how to create a good question

A multi-part form described @DVK [Require new users to post all of the needed parts of a question separately](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254386/require-new-users-to-post-all-of-the-needed-parts-of-a-question-separately) would do the trick but comments and answers point out the inflexibility. Detecting some elements would be easy to implement without any inflexibility aside from requiring they be somewhere in the post.

Are there elements that ***should*** be in every new comer's question? Suggestion from @marsh of a [question mark](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280027/required-question-mark-on-questions) was downvoted but elsewhere [automated analysis of a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270903/how-to-reduce-and-quickly-close-questions-that-are-merely-requirements?rq=1) got traction.

I propose `code` and a hyperlink. What counterexample exists in which a beginner's question wouldn't benefit from a back-ticked element? Beginners could be advised that they could use that to show any of the following

- relevant portion of their code
- data
- cut and pasted error
- output

What beginner's question wouldn't benefit from a hyperlink? Could be 
- documentation they're referencing
- source of code they're adapting
- other SO question they read

Teaching beginners the markdown elements for code and hyperlink would be useful to them, too.

Comment: In case you're wondering: [Unlike normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta invites the community to discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself behaves, as well as how the software itself works. On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that. What would be the best way for me to have promoted discussion of automated detection of required elements for beginners posts on SO? Should I have labelled it as discussion?

Comment: This is still a feature request; you're looking to add new functionality to the site, so it's tagged appropriately.  It could be that those who voted simply disagree with the proposal.

Comment: I changed it from feature request to discussion. I declined the temptation to delete and repost; it is starting as a discussion with -6 votes from the feature request.

Comment: ...No, it was tagged fine earlier.  You're still asking for functionality to be added to the site.  I wouldn't delete it yet, since you could learn a thing or two if someone answers it.

Comment: Why would you *need* to have a link in a question? That is just asking for link-rot.

Comment: Code counterexamples: [Single drawRect: implementation across multiple UIView subclasses](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32876613) [How to avoid circle observe in MVVM?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32452850) I've got a few others handy, but they were posted by higher-rep users, which probably disqualifies them in your eyes, but that brings me to another point: you're conflating beginners to programming and beginners to SO.

Answer (score 8):

A "good" question isn't something that's algorithmically straightforward to identify.  A good question may be one that's never been asked, has been asked a lot and doesn't have a common solution, or one that doesn't even involve code.

[Take the canonical `NullPointerException` question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/1079354) from Java.  This is an incredibly useful question since the answers describe both what an NPE is, and how to prevent one in numerous situations.  By your criterion, this question wouldn't be permissible.

What about those questions that ask about data structures or algorithms?  [Here's an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/1079354)  Again, by your criterion, this wouldn't be allowed, even though it's a fantastic question.

I'm not looking at the aspect of a question from a beginner.  Everyone's questions get treated the same, whether they're 1 rep or 10K rep.  Just because someone isn't a "beginner" on the site doesn't mean that they don't ask *horrible* questions.

So no, a proposal like this wouldn't work.  It's easier to determine what a bad question comprises of than what a good question would contain (which is why we have quality filters to catch a huge chunk of these).  If you find yourself running into a lot of them, downvote them as necessary so that they won't remain a problem for much longer.

Comment: The NPE and linked list posts both meet the backtick markdown criteria I propose. Neither meet the hyperlink criteria I propose. Both questions could be asked with a hyperlink. And both posts would benefit by showing research done so far by including a hyperlink.

Comment: @BBrown Neither of those canonical questions would benefit from links in the question. They are great questions as they stand with the purpose of the question being to provide a placeholder to add the canonical answers.

Comment: @BBrown:  ...Not really.  Doing some research is a plus, but I think in this scenario you're missing the forest for the trees.  A good question isn't one that just sticks to a set algorithm or a set way of being asked.